# How do I declare, send classes with unknown template argument into function?

Tags: c++, class, templates

Let's say I have a class DogClass that takes in something like this

```
DogClass<Poodle::Medium>
```

Where it could be be anything in the template. I need to do many different operations on them so I want to make a function like this.

```
void DogAnaylzer(DogClass<T>) {
    size = DogClass<T>.size();
    weight = DogClass<T>.weight();
    density = weight / size;
    ...
}
```

and I know that these methods exists for no matter what goes inside the template so I just want to write one function instead of making bunch for each and everything in . I think the an easy example would be how do I pass vector<T> to a function, with <T> possibly being anything but I know they all have vector<T>.size() and I want to make one function to deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function could itself be a template

```
template <typename T>
void DogAnaylzer(DogClass<T> const& dog) {
    auto const size = dog.size();
    auto const weight = dog.weight();
    auto const density = weight / size;
    ...
}
```

Note that you'd call methods off the instance (e.g. `dog.size()`) not the class itself (e.g. `DogClass<T>.size()`)

Comment: You've overlooked the fact that template classes can have static member functions.

Comment: @Peter you are correct, though based on their psuedo-code I would be surprised if that was the case here